# How to update column on other column change in inline edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, parsefloat

Free jqgrid contains 3 columns:  Price, Quantity and Sum.

html5 number input type is used.

If Sum column is changed in inline edit, Price column value should calculated using formula

> Price = Sum / Quantity;

I tried to implement this using jqgrid template below but it does not change price column since `input#Price` and `input#Quantity` are undefined.

Element ids are created from row id and are different in every row.
Jqgrid does not pass row id value to change event.

Which is best practice in free jqgrid to implement such calculations ?

```
var sumColumnTemplate = {
    "editoptions": {
        "type": "number", 
        "dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {
            $('input#Price').val(parseFloat(this.value) / parseFloat(    
               $('input#Quantity').val()  ));
        }
        }
};
```

Chrome inspect element shows that following markup is created for row in inline edit mode:

```
<tr role="row" id="1383" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" editable="1" aria-selected="false">
    ... lot of td s skipped

   <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:right;" class="" title="4" aria-describedby="grid_Quantity"><input type="number" class="grid-decimal-edit editable" id="1383_Quantity" name="Quantity" cm="[object Object]" icol="5" role="textbox" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"></td>

   <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:right;" class="" 
   aria-describedby="grid_Price"><input type="number" title="" maxlength="15" class="grid-decimal-edit editable" id="1383_Price" name="Price" cm="[object Object]" icol="6" role="textbox" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"></td>

   <td role="gridcell" style="text-align:right;" title="" aria-describedby="grid_Sum"><input type="number" title="" maxlength="15" class="grid-decimal-edit editable" id="1383_Sum" name="Sum" cm="[object Object]" icol="7" role="textbox" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"></td>
   ....
</tr>
```

table has many rows and 1383 in part of id is probably row number which is different for every row.

Which is best way to get numberic values form current row in inline edit mode ?

Bootstrap 3, jquery, jquery-ui, ASP.NET MVC 4, Razor views, .NET 4.6 are used.

**Update**

Column definitions:

```
{"label":"Quantity","name":"Quantity","index":"Quantity","searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge"],"maxlength":12,"size":12},"template":"number","formatoptions":{"thousandsSeparator":"","decimalPlaces":4,"defaultValue":""},"align":"right","editoptions":{"type":"number","step":"any","min":-999999,"max":9999999,"title":"","maxlength":12,"dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {dataChanged(e.target)}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
},{"type":"blur","fn":function(e) {}
}],"readonly":null,"class":"grid-decimal-edit","disabled":null},"editable":function(options){return getEditable(options,false);}
,"width":68,"classes":"","hidden":false},

{"label":"OstuPrice","name":"Price","index":"Price","searchoptions":{"sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge"],"maxlength":15,"size":15},"template":"number","formatoptions":{"thousandsSeparator":"","decimalPlaces":5,"defaultValue":""},"align":"right","editoptions":{"type":"number","step":"any","min":-99999999,"max":999999999,"title":"","maxlength":15,"dataEvents":[{"type":"change","fn":function(e) {dataChanged(e.target)}
},{"type":"focus","fn":function(e) {if(typeof e.target.ischanged=='undefined') {e.target.ischanged=false}}
},{"type":"blur","fn":function(e) {}
}],"readonly":null,"class":"grid-decimal-edit","disabled":null},"editable":function(options){return getEditable(options,false);}
,"width":75,"classes":"","hidden":false,"tere":"1234"},

{"template":sumColumnTemplate
,"label":"Sum","name":"Sum","width":80,"index":"Sum","hidden":false},
```

Comment: Could you post the definition of columns `Price` and `Quantity` and probably some other column where `sumColumnTemplate` be used? I see additionally `cm` and `icol` attributes, which should not exist in the current version (4.13.4) of free jqGrid. Which version you use?

Comment: I'm using 4.13.3-pre . I solved issue using `$('input[Name="Price"]')` and `$('input[Name="Quantity"]')` selectors. Is this best practice? In future other calculations using different columns needs implemented.

Comment: @Oleg . Variables cm and icol are used in code. How jqgrid converts those variables to column attributes ?

Comment: @Oleg I updated question and added column definitions. sumColumnTemplate definition in question is simplified. Actually it contains mostly same properties as in Price and Quantity columns colmodel posted

Comment: `4.13.3-pre` means some unknown preliminary version after version 4.13.2. I recommend you to update to the current release 4.13.4. You had the question about usage of `sumColumnTemplate`. **I asked you to include the definition of columns where `sumColumnTemplate´ is used. Could you do this?** The usage of `$('input[Name="Price"]')` is not good. It's better to get first the `<tr>` element by id (using `getGridRowById` method for example) and then use `jQuery.find('input[Name="Price"]')` fo search only inside of the row.

Comment: I don't see the usage of `sumColumnTemplate` in the column definition which you posted. Is `sumColumnTemplate` and `sumTemplate` the same?

Comment: @Oleg. Yes, they are same.  I changed question update and added this. It is used for Sum column, it is just shortcut not to define properties in Sum column colmodel.

Comment: @Oleg getGridRowById requires row id. Which is best practice to find row id in change event ?

Comment: If you have event **in the row** then it would be the best choice to use `$(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow')` instead of `getGridRowById`: `$(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow').find('input[Name="Price"]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem exist because you use `template` property with the object as the value. Starting with jqGrid 4.7 (see [my old pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/631)) it's possible to define "standard" templates and to use there as strings.

One need to use the following code to define

```
$.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
$.jgrid.cmTemplate = $.jgrid.cmTemplate || {};
$.jgrid.cmTemplate.mySum = {
    editoptions: {
        type: "number", 
        dataEvents: [{
            type: "change",
            fn: function(e) {
                // some code
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

One can use now `template: "mySum"`:

```
{"template":"mySum","label":"Sum","name":"Sum","width":80}
```

instead of `template: sumColumnTemplate`:

```
{"template":sumColumnTemplate,"label":"Sum","name":"Sum","width":80,
"index":"Sum","hidden":false}
```

Comment: Why `template:"mySum"` is better than `template:sumColumnTemplate` ? They procude exactly same result by mySum requires also additional assignment to cmTemplate.

Comment: @Andrus: `template:"mySum"` contains **string** value, which van be serialize/deserialized via JSON. Thus you can load such `colModel` from the server via JSON. On the other side `template:sumColumnTemplate` contains **functions** inside the object and can't be used inside of JSON data.

Comment: Should row id determined in change event for calculations? If yes, which is best practice to find it ? `$(this).closest('tr')` ?

Comment: how to apply template after colmodel is defined to override existing settings and add new change event handler to existing change event handlers which may be defined in base template referenced by template property and in colmodel ?

Comment: @Andrus: If I correctly understand you, then you need to find `<input>` for some fields during inline editing. All the `<input>` elements are inside of the same row. Thus `$(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow')` or `$(this).closest('tr.jqgrow')` get you the current row (`<tr>`) and  `$(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow').find('input[Name="Price"]')` or `$(this).closest('tr.jqgrow').find('input[Name="Price"]')` search for the input only inside of the current row.

Comment: @Andrus: You don't need to apply template. You can just set the changes which you need. The usage of `setColProp` make the code mostly easy. If you do need to combine some templates then you should use `$.extend(true, {}, template1, template2, ...)` where `template1` can be  `$.jgrid.cmTemplate.mySum` or `sumColumnTemplate`.

Comment: I used `var sumColumnTemplate=$.extend(true, $.jgrid.cmTemplate.number, {  editoptions: {
        type: "number", 
        dataEvents:[{type:"change",fn:function(e) { ...
        }}]
        }});` to create inherited template. Is this OK  ?

Comment: @Andrus: I'm not sure that it's full correct. Which column you need to change? Do you need to change one column or multiple one? I think you don't need to use new `sumColumnTemplate` variable. On the other side you can probably use `setColProp` with `sumColumnTemplate` as the value to apply new settings on some column/columns.

Comment: I need to change only Sum column. It can be probably changed to inject $.extend commad to razor view to change generated colmodel before it is rendered. `setColProp` can used to change column properties only after jqgrid is created. After `setColProp` usage if visible properties are changed grid needs refreshed. So it is better to use $.extend to avoid additional refresh, isn't it ?

Comment: Is there some event which occurs only one time after grid is created but before rendered? Maybe it is most reasonable to call `setColProp` in this event. `loadComplete` occurs every time after grid is loaded. Can jquery `one()` or boolean flag `firstLoad` used in `loadComplete` to run `setColProp` only once

Comment: @Andrus: There are exist `beforeInitGrid` callback in free jqGrid. It can be used to modify **any option or callback of jqGrid at the beginning of creating jqGrid**. You can build/modify `colModel` inside of `beforeInitGrid`.

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like colmodel customization code should subscribe to jquery `jqGridbeforeInitGrid` event and call setColProp in this is event handler.

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! You are almost correct, but one can't use `setColProp` or any other jqGrid method inside of `beforeInitGrid` callback or `jqGridbeforeInitGrid` event because jqGrid is not yet exist. You have to find the item in `colModel` by comparing the `name` property of every item like I described before.

Comment: It looks like in this case there is no reason to use jqgrid event and this modification can done before calling jqgrid constructur directly in code ? Where you described `You have to find the item in colModel by comparing the name property of every item`  ? `setColProp` uses `iColByName` array created by `buildColNameMap` method. Should those methods extracted from jqgrid source code as standalone methods to be used to change colmodel before jqgrid is created ?

Comment: @Andrus: Sorry, but you asked almost the same thing in above comments. One have many ways to implement your requirements. You use some mix between generation of the option of jqGrid in C#, in to razor view and in JavaScript code. You can modify/generate `colModel` at any place **before jqGrid is created** and you can change many modification dynamically. You should choose the best place for your environment yourself.

Comment: I tried to use setColProp. It ignores template property setting. For other properties it works. I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318419/how-to-apply-column-template-after-jqgrid-is-created